# How to create fifth drive for ubuntu on Win7?

Tags: installation, windows-7, drive

I have Win7 with 4 drives (basic disk) and a lot of unallocated space....
Now I want to create 5th drive for Ubuntu... 
But windows don't let me create 5th without making the disk Dynamic.
I don't want to make the disk Dynamic at all...

On my other computer there is a basic disk with more than 4 drives! on win7 and it doesn't prompt me to make it dynamic(like a good guy :)).

As far as possible I want to install Ubuntu on separate drive and not inside windows...
What can I do?

Thanks in advanced....

EDIT--> One of the 4 partitions is: "System Reserved" only 100 MB active partition which is not show in Computer... Is it necessary? What if I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a BIOS and hardware limitation, not an operating system one.  You can only have four primary partitions on any physical hard drive.

The solution is to delete one of the primary partitions and make an extended partition in its place.  You can then have as many logical partitions inside the extended partition as you want.

You can do all of this with a good partition editor such as Gparted.  Don't forget to backup the data on the partition before you delete it - it won't be there after you hit the delete button!

Comment: Thanks... Can I do it all using Windows' disk management?

Comment: I would use GParted from the Ubuntu live CD/USB (click try Ubuntu when you boot from the installation disk).

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use Window's disk management to do this, however if you need help with it you would need to find another forum to ask questions about it.

Comment: Ok I made an extended partition and 2 logical drives...
Now I am going to install Ubuntu on 1 of the logical drives... :)
Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, if you make 4th partition using ***Disk Management***, it is automatically selected to be ***Logical Partition*** (*Extended Partition*). But you cannot convert a partition from ***Primary*** to ***Logical***, neither you can choose which type of partition you want to create.

If you want to select the partition type by yourself, you can refer to this article: http://www.partition-magic-windows7.com/res/create-partition-windows7.html. (Basically, it asks you to download another disk management software and do it using that software).

Other queries are nicely answered by [fabricator4](https://askubuntu.com/a/188058/83046).